# adding space upper and down Image

Tags: spacing, white-space

I have more sequences of the image with the text between there, from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247435/how-to-remove-blank-spaces-above-and-below-inserted-images/247453#comment1293763_247453) I resolve the problem of the withe space but now I have too a little space from the image.

I want to add the space upper and down Image, is it possible?

this is the problem

[image]

This is my example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{toptesi}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,graphicx}


\begin{document}

L’operatore OP\_2 verifica che nello stack ci siano 2 elementi, successivamente vengono inserite le tre chiavi pubbliche, ottenendo così uno stato come in Figura \ref{fig:stackmultsing02}.

{\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{images/script/multisig/2.png}
\captionof{figure}{Stato dello stack dopo la verifica con OP\_2 e l’inserimento nello stack delle chiavi pubbliche.\label{fig:stackmultsing02}}
\par}

Infine le firme vengono verificate con le chiavi pubbliche mediante l’operatore OP\_CHECKMULTISIG in maniera iterativa, cioè la prima firma viene confrontata con tutte le chiavi pubbliche e l’azione si ripete per tutte le firme inserite, come in Figura \ref{fig:stackmultsing03}.

{\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{images/script/multisig/3.png}
\captionof{figure}{Esecuzione dell’operatore OP\_CHECKMULTISIG per la verifica delle chiavi \cite{learnmeabitcoin:p2ms}.\label{fig:stackmultsing03}}
\par}

\subsection{P2SH}
Lo script {\it pay-to-script-hash \/} venne introdotto nel 2012, per semplificare l’uso degli script in transazioni complesse: infatti molto spesso accade di avere script molto grandi, come uno script P2MS 14:15 che comporta un aumento della complessità dello script di sblocco; la motivazione dell’introduzione dello script P2SH è stata la semplificazione di quest’ultimo, come se fosse un normale pagamento ad un indirizzo Bitcoin.
Questa nuova tipologia semplifica notevolmente lo script di blocco, perché sarà popolato solo dal suo hash, a discapito però dell’aggiunta di una copia dello script di blocco all’interno dello script di sblocco. Si considere, ad esempio il seguente script P2SH:
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Why you not use `figure` float environment? If you not like for some reason, enclose your images in `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}`.

Comment: The problem is illustrated in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247435/how-to-remove-blank-spaces-above-and-below-inserted-images/247453#comment1293763_247453)

Comment: From given link is not seen, what is your problem.

Comment: With more image I have them with space dead in all my files because I just used the `\begin{figure}[H]` and I resolve my problem with there code. But now I have a problem because not exist a space to section text and the figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP, on another thread, invited me to comment/answer.

Normally, one can use the `center` environment.  However, the OP seemed, for reasons that are not wholly clear, to prefer the `\centering` approach with a specified space manually added.

Thanks to Zarko for pointing to another thread for other (likely prefereable) ways to deal with this issue, [How to change the spacing between figures/tables and text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-figures-tables-and-text)

Here, I just create a macro `\mygap` which can be judiciously added after `\centering` and/or before the closing `\par` for additional vertical space.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{toptesi}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,graphicx}
\newcommand\mygap{\vspace{10pt}}

\begin{document}

L’operatore OP\_2 verifica che nello stack ci siano 2 elementi, successivamente vengono inserite le tre chiavi pubbliche, ottenendo così uno stato come in Figura \ref{fig:stackmultsing02}.

{\centering\mygap
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{Stato dello stack dopo la verifica con OP\_2 e l’inserimento nello stack delle chiavi pubbliche.\label{fig:stackmultsing02}}
\mygap\par}

Infine le firme vengono verificate con le chiavi pubbliche mediante l’operatore OP\_CHECKMULTISIG in maniera iterativa, cioè la prima firma viene confrontata con tutte le chiavi pubbliche e l’azione si ripete per tutte le firme inserite, come in Figura \ref{fig:stackmultsing03}.

{\centering\mygap
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Esecuzione dell’operatore OP\_CHECKMULTISIG per la verifica delle chiavi \cite{learnmeabitcoin:p2ms}.\label{fig:stackmultsing03}}
\mygap\par}

\subsection{P2SH}
Lo script {\it pay-to-script-hash \/} venne introdotto nel 2012, per semplificare l’uso degli script in transazioni complesse: infatti molto spesso accade di avere script molto grandi, come uno script P2MS 14:15 che comporta un aumento della complessità dello script di sblocco; la motivazione dell’introduzione dello script P2SH è stata la semplificazione di quest’ultimo, come se fosse un normale pagamento ad un indirizzo Bitcoin.
Questa nuova tipologia semplifica notevolmente lo script di blocco, perché sarà popolato solo dal suo hash, a discapito però dell’aggiunta di una copia dello script di blocco all’interno dello script di sblocco. Si considere, ad esempio il seguente script P2SH:
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply use `\begin{center}  \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}\captionof{figure}{Esecuzione dell’operatore OP\_CHECKMULTISIG per la verifica delle chiavi \cite{learnmeabitcoin:p2ms}.\label{fig:stackmultsing03}}\end{center}`?

Comment: Thanks fot this

Comment: @Zarko The thread where I was contacted was specifically about eliminating  vertical space and thus to not use the `center` environment.  Why the OP prefers this approach, I am not sure, but it may be related to how much vertical space he desires.  Not sure.

Comment: @Zarko I have edited to discuss the issue a little.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I must confess that I do not understood OP question. To me it is unclear. It seems to me that (s)he want to invent a wheel again. I would rather stick with `figure` float and than consider https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-figures-tables-and-text .

Comment: @Zarko I think I can interpret why the OP rejects the `figure` approach.  Based on his words, "I have them with space dead in all my files" I take that to mean that the `figure` environment introduces an unacceptable amount of vertical "dead space" into the document.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, well, this can be handled as explained in given link in my previous comment. However, OP accept your answer :-), so all my comments are now irrelevant :-(